# how to identify duplicate value and get the list of count from unique value from JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Please find my JSON below:  I want to identify unique user and get the corresponding unique users value count. For Example:

userID: **user1** has 3 records and I want to form the JSON like below:

**Expected Result JSON:**

```
[ {
  "userId" : "user1",
  "success" : 1,
  "error" : 0,
  "cancel" : 0,
  "visit" : 3,
  "enroll" : 2,
  "uninstall" : 0
}]
```

user1 has 1 **SUCCESS** , 2 **ENROLLED** and 3** VISITED** and remaining values are **null** so we have to count as **0**.

Same way we have to do for remaining users also.

Can you someone help how i can achieve this using javascript/jquery.

**Main JSON:**

```
[ {
  "userId" : "user1",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user1",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user1",
  "success" : "SUCCESS",
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user2",
  "success" : "SUCCESS",
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user2",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user2",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user2",
  "success" : "SUCCESS",
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user3",
  "success" : "SUCCESS",
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user3",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user4",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user4",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : "CANCELLED",
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user4",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : "CANCELLED",
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : null,
  "uninstall" : null
}, {
  "userId" : "user4",
  "success" : null,
  "error" : null,
  "cancel" : null,
  "visit" : "VISITED",
  "enroll" : "ENROLLED",
  "uninstall" : null
} ]
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oLzkwzxb/2/ ?

Comment: Just wanted to check in to see if you had found a solution yet.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly :) Thanks Arun!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a few steps here, you would first want to `filter` the array down to only elements matching the `userId`.

```
function isUser(userRecord){
        return userRecord.userId === userId;
}
```

Then would want to `map`, the values to a common data format, converting your values into a simple `1` or `0`.

```
function createSummaryRecords(userRecord){
    return {
        "userId" : userRecord.userId,
        "success" : !userRecord.success ? 0 : 1,
        "error" : !userRecord.error ? 0 : 1,
        "cancel" : !userRecord.cancel ? 0 : 1,
        "visit" : !userRecord.visit ? 0 : 1,
        "enroll" : !userRecord.enroll ? 0 : 1,
        "uninstall" : !userRecord.uninstall ? 0 : 1
    };
}
```

Then would want to `reduce` the array to a summary of the users entries.

```
function sumarize(previousValue, currentValue){
    return {
        "userId" : currentValue.userId,
        "success" : previousValue.success + currentValue.success,
        "error" : previousValue.error + currentValue.error,
        "cancel" : previousValue.cancel + currentValue.cancel,
        "visit" : previousValue.visit + currentValue.visit,
        "enroll" : previousValue.enroll + currentValue.enroll,
        "uninstall" : previousValue.uninstall + currentValue.uninstall
    }
}
```

Example chaining:

```
allUsersEntries
    .filter(isUser)
    .map(createSummaryRecords)
    .reduce(sumarize);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/po6nry25/1/

Although a `foreach` with has own property may be more efficent in this case, this approach allows you to document what your intent is, and allows you to vary your implementation to check for specific values in your `createSummaryRecords` step.